# JS add array's values to object

Tags: javascript, object

i have an array of object and result object. How can i add all array's elements to result object

```
let result = {
    list: 'example',
    foo: 'something'
}

let array = [
    {
        item: 'a',
        value: 'a',
    },
    {
        item: 'b',
        value: 'b',
    },
    {
        item: 'c',
        value: 'c',
    },

]

let result = {
    list: 'example',
    foo: 'something',
    array
}
console.log(result);
```

I need the result to be:

```
{
    list: 'example',
    foo: 'something',
    item[0]: 'a',
    value[0]: 'a',
    item[1]: 'b',
    value[1]: 'b',
    item[2]: 'c',
    value[2]: 'c'
}
```

How should i add an array? I'm trying something like JSON.stringify, but could'n get required format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could iterate the objects of the array and assign the values to a combined key.

```js
var result = { list: 'example', foo: 'something' },
    array = [ { item: 'a', value: 'a' }, { item: 'b', value: 'b' }, { item: 'c', value: 'c' }];

array.forEach((o, i) =>
    Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => result[`${k}[${i}]`] = v));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through the array and populate the desired properties using [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
let result = {
  list: 'example',
  foo: 'something'
}

let array = [{
    item: 'a',
    value: 'a',
  },
  {
    item: 'b',
    value: 'b',
  },
  {
    item: 'c',
    value: 'c',
  }
]

array.forEach((obj, index) => {
  result[`item[${index}]`] = obj.item;
  result[`value[${index}]`] = obj.value;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like that ?

```js
array.map(element => Object.assign(result, {[element.item]: element.value}))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by

```
array.unshift(result);
```

If it's not what you want, you may use loop to go through all element in the array and add them one by one (if you trying to get each element out but not with one '{item, value}' element).